# VB.NET Show message after FTP upload complete

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I'm trying to create a uploader to FTP, although the file uploads perfectly, I am just wondering how I would be able to show a message after the ftp process has complete.

```
 Close()
        Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        Dim r As New Random
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 1 To 8
            Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, 35)
            sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
        Next


        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            sc.CaptureDeskTopRectangle(Me.boundsRect).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
                wc.UploadData("ftp://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@MYSITE.COM/" + sb.ToString() + ".png", ms.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
```

How would I manage this?

Edit: Also as you can see I use a random string.. although If I use sb.ToString() twice will it give me the exact same result for both? If not how can I manage this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the Random as Static. The `UploadData` has a `UploadDataCompleted` event you can listen for.

```
    Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    Static r As New Random
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 1 To 8
        Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, 35)
        sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
    Next


    Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        sc.CaptureDeskTopRectangle(Me.boundsRect).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
            AddHandler wc.UploadDataCompleted, AddressOf UploadCompleted
            wc.UploadData("ftp://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@MYSITE.COM/" + sb.ToString() + ".png", ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using

  Private Sub UploadCompleted(sender As Object, e As Net.UploadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    'do completed work here
  End Sub
```

I don't think you can use the UploadData like that. Here is a [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example of ftp uploading.

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
' Get the object used to communicate with the server.
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm"), FtpWebRequest)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

' This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com")

' Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
Dim sourceStream As New StreamReader("testfile.txt")
Dim fileContents As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd())
sourceStream.Close()
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length

Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length)
requestStream.Close()

Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription)

response.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Although I had close() in the uploadcompleted sub, although it did not close. So I also tried about.ShowDialog() but did not popup. The image uploads but still does not tell me when its done.

Comment: Not sure why your calling `Close` before that code - wouldn't you put that at the end? Did you see the Completed event?

Comment: Ignore close() that was just a test I was doing. I want close() after the upload is done. so `Private Sub UploadCompleted(sender As Object, e As Net.UploadDataCompletedEventArgs)
   me.close()
  End Sub`

Comment: If that is what you want to occur with the completion of the upload.

Comment: Yes but it does not work.. As I said I also tried putting about.showdialog() though it didnt show either.

Comment: I am not sure what your talking about, I didn't see where you were talking about this dialog stuff???

Comment: I am wanting to close the .. form once upload completes. I am just saying I replaced close() with about. to see if it would work, but it didnt. But nor did it close.. I used your code and put `Private Sub UploadCompleted(sender As Object, e As Net.UploadDataCompletedEventArgs)    me.close()`   End Sub but it did not work.

Comment: You didn't miss putting the Addhandler statement, right? did you set a breakpoint to see if the code executes? Is there anything in the form_closing event that would stop the form from closing?

Comment: I don't know why your code is not working. My code should be, please check this as answer if that is true for you. The other part was not what you were asking for.

Comment: I was asking for a working code in showing a message after ftp is completed. Although changed to close() but .. it still does not work

Comment: Marked your question as correct, although it did not work. I might have just done something wrong.

Comment: You did not need to check it if it does not work, I had given answers to 2 things in your question, and it seemed like you were adding more problems. Did you Try/Catch your Upload part to see if there is an error with the Upload?

Comment: Well if it did not work, the answer is incorrect.. is it not? The point of asking a question is to get an answer to get it fixed.

Comment: Well that was awful thick. I fixed the Random part. I gave the correct way to listen to the Completed event. That is what you asked for and they do work - so it must be on you!

Comment: Nothing was actually wrong with the random string. I asked "Edit: Also as you can see I use a random string.. although If I use sb.ToString() twice will it give me the exact same result for both? If not how can I manage this??" although this was not my main question and it was already fixed. It was true that it would work without editing. But anyways since you just keep arguing decided to take away 'correct answer'. Thanks anyhow.